# How to change an Apple Flash Projector app icon?

Tags: macos, flash, icons

I would like to change the icon of my Flash.app projector.

I used img2icns to make the new mac icon but how can I make it use this icon ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I used is to open the icon (or any transparent image) in 24bits with `Preview`. Make a selection `Cmd + a` and copy the selection `Cmd + c`. On the app, view info with `Cmd + i` and click on the icon in the upper left. Paste with `Cmd + v`.

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl + click` in the file and choose *'Show package contents'*. Within the .app is a folder called `Resources` containing two icon files. Just drag you're custom icons in there and overwrite the originals.

Comment: It doesn't seams to be enougth on a USB FAT32 Key. I don't understand why... As soon as I copy the app on the desktop I can change the icon but before I can't.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get what you're saying here. Did or didn't it work?